# Merge two streams to get result

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of model Config which looks like

```
class Config extends Model{
String name;
String type;
JsonNode config;
}
```

On querying the db, I get config for name 'abc' (which is passed by user) and id 'default'. There can be 3 config types (type1, type2, type3)

Requirement: If any config type is missing for the user input, config from 'default' is returned.
For example:
On querying for only name 'abc', I get

```
[
  {
    "name": "abc",
    "type": "type1",
    "config": []
  },
  {
    "name": "abc",
    "type": "type2",
    "config": []
  }
]
```

```
[
  {
    "name": "default",
    "type": "type1",
    "config": []
  },
  {
    "name": "default",
    "type": "type2",
    "config": []
  }
  {
    "name": "default",
    "type": "type3",
    "config": []
  }
]
```

As config of type3 is missing response should be

```
[
  {
    "name": "abc",
    "type": "type1",
    "config": []
  },
  {
    "name": "abc",
    "type": "type2",
    "config": []
  },
  {
    "name": "default",
    "type": "type3",
    "config": []
  }
]
```

**What I have done:**

I have a map <id, Config>. In a db query, I fetch Config for both id 1 and 0 in a list.

```
Map<String, JsonNode> customConfig = configList.stream()
            .filter(o -> o.getOrgId().equals(1))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Config::getKey, Config::getValue));
Map<String, JsonNode> defaultConfig = configList.stream()
                .filter(o -> o.getId().equals(0))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Config::getKey, Config::getValue));
```

And then I just do

```
configList.getOrDefault(type, defaultConfig.get(type));
```

**What I want to do:**

I want to merge the two streams into a single stream.

**What I've tried:**
I looked into using groupingBy along with collectingAndThen in collectors but got confused on how to get the final result.

Comment: It’s not clear what you want. In your example you say config of type 3 is missing, but immediately below that you show a JSON containing type 3. Also, what’s the relation between id and type? Please clarify your question.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Changed id to name for better understanding. "what’s the relation between id and type" --> some names will not have configs of some types. When that happens, we need to substitute config from default user.

Comment: Even before your edit, your code example was inconsistently calling two differently named methods, `getOrgId()` and `getId()`. But after the edit, it’s even worse as you have changed your example data to have a `name` property of type `String`, even less matching your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on the same method you can directly filter by the two options:

```
Map<String, JsonNode> customConfig = configList.stream()
        .filter(o -> o.getOrgId().equals(1) || o.getOrgId().equals(0))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Config::getKey, Config::getValue));
```

Another option is to return a stream and use the concat option:

```
Stream<Config> stream1 = configList.stream()
        .filter(o -> o.getOrgId().equals(1));
Stream<Config> stream2 = configList.stream()
            .filter(o -> o.getId().equals(0));
Map<String, JsonNode> config = Stream.concat(stream1, stream2)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Config::getKey, Config::getValue));
```

Comment: your first code block does not serve my purpose bcz it will override id 1's config with id 0's config and i dont want that. If id 1's config do not exist, only then i want to fallback to the default configs.

Comment: Then you don't want to merge the streams (as the post says)
You want to get the config under id '1' and, if empty, get the config under id '2'
I will try to give an example of code in the post

Comment: Yes, what i meant was to use a single stream and "merge" the behaviour. I do not want to iterate twice.

Comment: Can you provide more info? Is configList a List of Config objects? If it's only Config object, it's possible to have duplicates on the list? Or it will range from 0 to 2 (assuming 0=type1,...). What does the "getOrgId" method do?